# How to get all assigned Smarty variables while running the template?

Tags: php, smarty

I would like to get all variables assigned to Smarty inside the template. For example, if I have this code

```
$smarty->assign('name', 'Fulano');
$smarty->assign('age', '22');
$result = $this->smarty->fetch("file:my.tpl");
```

I would like to have a `my.tpl` like the one below:

```
{foreach from=$magic_array_of_variables key=varname item=varvalue}
{$varname} is {$varvalue}
{/foreach}
```

such as the content of result would be

```
name is Fulano
age is 22
```

So, is there a way to get this `$magic_array_of_variables`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### all code below is smarty2

All smarty variables are held inside the $smarty->_tpl_vars object, so before fetching() your template, you could do:

```
$smarty->assign('magic_array_of_variables', $smarty->_tpl_vars);
```

Since this may be impractical, you could also write a small smarty plugin function that does something similar:

```
function smarty_function_magic_array_of_variables($params, &$smarty) {
    foreach($smarty->_tpl_vars as $key=>$value) {
        echo "$key is $value<br>";
    }
}
```

and from your tpl call it with:

```
{magic_array_of_variables}
```

Alternatively, in this function you can do:

```
function smarty_function_magic_array_of_variables($params, &$smarty) {
    $smarty->_tpl_vars['magic_array_of_variables'] =  $smarty->_tpl_vars;
}
```

and in your template:

```
{magic_array_of_variables}
{foreach from=$magic_array_of_variables key=varname item=varvalue}
{$varname} is {$varvalue}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign an array to your smarty variable. Something like this:

```
$array = array('name' => 'Fulano', 'age' => '22');
```

when you assign this to your template with the name `magic_array_of_variables`, the exact smarty template you provided should give the output you want

Comment: I would like to do it but that is no solution to me, unfortunately, because I have no access to the Smarty object - it is generated and managed by a framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to iterate the assigned variables. That said, [getTemplateVars()](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl) returns an associative array of all assigned values.

Like @perikilis described, you can simply register a plugin function to push the result of getTemplateVars() back to the assigned variables list. If you wanted to prevent some data duplication and other weirdness, you might want to only assign the array_keys() and access the actual variables like `{${$varname}}` (Smarty3).

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if {debug} at the start of your tpl is that you need.

Comment: Well, it's been 84 years :D But seriously, not in this case: I really wanted to process the values from the variables. (Today, I'd probably create an array with the values I wanted from the start, it tends to be cleaner anyway).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32321705)