# reset multiple variables on one line with Smarty

Tags: php, variables, smarty, variable-assignment, template-engine

I have a number of variables that I would like to reset to blank in Smarty, however i'd like to avoid having multiple lines like this:

```
{assign var='background_id' value=''}
{assign var='background_link' value=''}
```

Is there a way to reset a number of variables in one line with Smarty as you can do in PHP, Perl and the like?

There's nothing in the Smarty docs for this.

Comment: I don't know anything about `Smarty`, but have you tried a `foreach()` loop?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be possible with a foreach loop. But it's essentially just the same as having individual lines as i'd need to define the elements to loop through.

Comment: Yes, but it is less code than above. As I said, I do not really know anything about Smarty, so this is as far as my help can really go on that front, but IMO you might as well just use a `foreach` loop. Its not too much code. Do you want me to post an example?

Comment: @BenCarey Thanks for your help, Ben. It's fine i'm familiar with Smarty foreach loops, so there's no need. I was interested to find out if there was a way to do multiple assignation with Smarty.

Comment: check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799652/how-to-get-all-assigned-smarty-variables-while-running-the-template

Comment: @sofl I suppose by doing that I would have to define all the variables to set within my PHP, rather than the Smarty template.